# Ler HTML dentro de um confirmButtonText do plugin SweetAlert

Tags: jquery, html, plugin

Possuo uma ação originada pelo plugin SweetAlert que precisa de um botão com texto bem extenso por se tratar de um opção muito sensível e que pode acarretar em erros.

```
 swal({
                            title: data['title'],
                            text: data['msg'],
                            type: 'warning',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            closeOnConfirm: true,
                            confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar exclusão (Essa ação não é recomendada \n, <small>Deletar este colaborador pode acarretar em inconsistencias nos dados anteriores, você pode torna-lo inativo, ou registrar um desligamento de funcionário.</small>.)',
                            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar e voltar'
                        },
                                function (isConfirm) {
                                    alert();
                                });
```

A minha dúvida é básicamente:

> Como fazer com que o plugin leia o HTML passado para
>   'confirmButtonText' ? Ou não tem como fazer isso ?

Comment: Não é comum um botão ter um texto tão longo assim. Você já pensou em colocar no botão somente o texto "Confirmar exclusão" e exibir o aviso sobre a ação no corpo do alerta?

Comment: Não é possível, pois no corpo eu ja tenho um texto descrevendo umas coisas, essa é uma função muito critica do sistema, preciso da descrição detalhada.

Comment: Veja o SweetAlert2, foi adicionado suporte a HTML nos botões: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta foi o comentário do @Renato Diniz na pergunta.

Alterei para SweetAlert2, problema resolvido.

Answer (score 0):

acredito que seja isso que voce queira, a tag `<small>` nao vai funcionar pq o sweetAlert nao oferece suporte a html.

```
swal("Mensagem", {
    icon: "warning",
  buttons: {
    btn1: "Confirmar exclusão (Essa ação não é recomendada \n, <small>Deletar este colaborador pode acarretar em inconsistencias nos dados anteriores, você pode torna-lo inativo, ou registrar um desligamento de funcionário.</small>.",
    btn2: "Cancelar"
  },
})
.then((value) => {
  switch (value) {

    case "btn1":
      return true;
      break;

    case "btn2":
      return false;
      break;

    default:
      swal("404");
  }
});
```